# How to fix a line of text links near top of page?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, alignment

Three rows of text links near top of page shift up to top when a link is pressed, obscuring a line of text already at top. How can I anchor the position of the three rows?

```
<!-- Styles for three rows of header text that shift upwards when I click on any link --!>

 /* Style for the fixed header */
        .header {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            padding: 10px;
            z-index: 10000;
            text-align: center;}

  /* Style for each row of links */
       .header-row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-bottom: 10px;}

<!-- divs for the three rows of text that shift upwards when any link is pressed--!>

<div class="header">
    <div class="header-row">
        <a href="#text1">One</a>
        <a href="#text2">Two</a>
        <a href="#text3">Three</a>
        <a href="#text4">Four</a>
  </div>

    <div class="header-row">
        <a href="#text5">Five</a>
        <a href="#text6">Six</a>
        <a href="#text7">Seven</a>
        <a href="#text8">Eight</a>
    </div>
 
<!-- The following link -- on third tow -- shifts the page down so the obscured top row of text reappears --!>

  <div class="header-row">
        <a href="#top">Return to table of contents</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Styles for the single row of text links at top of page that disappear when any of the links in the lower three rows are pressed -->

  .fixed-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Center the links horizontally */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 10000;}

.fixed-row a {
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;}

<!-- Single row of text links at top of page that disappear when the three rows below it rise --!> 
 <div class="fixed-row">
    <a href="index.html">Page One</a>
    <a href="two.html">Page Two</a>
    <a href="three.html">Page Three</a>
    <a href="main/four.html">Page Four</a>
</div>
```

I shifted the position of the styles, shifted the position of the "top" anchor and neither worked. I also altered z-index settings, that did not work either.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask); in particular the part about providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Stack Overflow has tools to provide an [inline live demo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for why `<a href="#top">` is acting like `<a href="#">` and automatically going to the top of the page without something like `id="top"` being set anywhere, that's new to me. Perhaps it's a newer browser feature/recommendation/expectation.

`<div class="header">` has `position: sticky; top: 0;`, therefore it "sticks" to the top of the viewport when scrolling.

`<div class="fixed-row">` does not have `position` declared, therefore it defaults to "static" and scrolls out of view. The `top` and `z-index` declarations have no effect because the element is static.

1. Declare `position: sticky` for `.fixed-row`
2. Calculate the `top` value for `.header` by adding the combined top and bottom padding declared for `.fixed-row` to the height of one line of text.
   Ideally, you'd use `1lh` for the value of 1 line-height. Disappointingly, Firefox does not support the `lh` unit. [Can I use `lh`?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_lh) However, I find line-height to be 1.125 times the font-size, which is easily represented with the `em` unit.

```css
.fixed-row {
  position: sticky;
}

.header {
  top: calc(1.125em + 20px);
}
```

```css
.fixed-row {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fixed-row a {
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(1.125em + 20px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}



body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.content {
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-row">
  <a href="index.html">Page One</a>
  <a href="two.html">Page Two</a>
  <a href="three.html">Page Three</a>
  <a href="main/four.html">Page Four</a>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="header-row">
    <a href="#text1">One</a>
    <a href="#text2">Two</a>
    <a href="#text3">Three</a>
    <a href="#text4">Four</a>
  </div>

  <div class="header-row">
    <a href="#text5">Five</a>
    <a href="#text6">Six</a>
    <a href="#text7">Seven</a>
    <a href="#text8">Eight</a>
  </div>

  <div class="header-row">
    <a href="#top">Return to table of contents</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="content">Content</div>
```

This can still cause issues on very narrow viewports when the text wraps into two lines. It would be better to nest the two sections into one sticky parent section.

```css
nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.fixed-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fixed-row a {
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}



body {
  margin: 0;
}

div.content {
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="fixed-row">
    <a href="index.html">Page One</a>
    <a href="two.html">Page Two</a>
    <a href="three.html">Page Three</a>
    <a href="main/four.html">Page Four</a>
  </div>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-row">
      <a href="#text1">One</a>
      <a href="#text2">Two</a>
      <a href="#text3">Three</a>
      <a href="#text4">Four</a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-row">
      <a href="#text5">Five</a>
      <a href="#text6">Six</a>
      <a href="#text7">Seven</a>
      <a href="#text8">Eight</a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-row">
      <a href="#top">Return to table of contents</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="content">Content</div>
```